# Getting started with chef, and running composer install on deploy

Tags: laravel, chef-infra, composer-php, laravel-4

We're looking to deploy a few [Laravel4](http://laravel.com) based PHP apps on amazon with OpsWorks, this requires a few things:

- Grab code from git
- Download composer.phar from getcomposer.com
- Run `php composer.phar install`
- Change permissions on a few specific folders

I'm completely fresh with it comes to chef, so initially looking for a place to get to grips with the basics of chef, and then how to achieve the tasks above, would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no Chef guru (I usually use Puppet) but try the following:

### Grab code from git

You may want to execute a wget command (see examples below).

If you want something more sophisticated see http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html

```
deploy_revision "/path/to/application" do
  repo 'ssh://name-of-git-repo/repos/repo.git'
  migrate false
  purge_before_symlink %w{one two folder/three}
  create_dirs_before_symlink []
  symlinks(
    "one"   => "one",
    "two"   => "two",
    "three" => "folder/three"
  )
  before_restart do
    # some Ruby code
  end
  notifies :restart, "service[foo]"
  notifies :restart, "service[bar]"
end
```

### Download composer.phar from getcomposer.com

I would execute a wget.

I lifted some code from here: http://cookingclouds.com/2012/06/23/chef-simple-cookbook-example/

It's basically just doing a wget in a specific folder, extracting the contents of the tar & updating some permissions on the new files. It only does this if the folder doesn't already exist.

```
# Run a bash shell -  download and extract composer
bash "install_composer" do
     user "root"
     cwd "/folder/to/extact/to"
     code <<-EOH
       wget http://getcomposer.com/composer.tar.gz
       tar -xzf composer.tar.gz
       chown -R user:group /folder/to/extact/to
     EOH
     not_if "test -d /folder/to/extact/to"
end
```

### Run php composer.phar install

http://docs.opscode.com/resource_execute.html

```
execute "composer install" do
  command "php composer.phar install && touch /var/log/.php_composer_installed"
  creates "/var/log/.php_composer_installed"
  action :run
end
```

This will only run it once, otherwise you can remove the "creates" and it will run it each time.

### Change permissions on a few specific folders

http://docs.opscode.com/resource.html

```
directory "/tmp/folder" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0755
  action :create
end
```

If the directory already exists, nothing will happen. If the directory was changed in any way, the resource is marked as updated.

### Finally

I find the search handy, browsing stuff on the Chef site seems to be hopeless (too much stuff to dig through). http://docs.opscode.com/search.html

Comment: Went with a similar setup, however I'm no longer downloading composer.phar on deployment, as I've already had the case where the composer site is down, which kills the whole deployment site. Instead I now have composer.phar in the git repo.

Answer (score 2):

I would go pretty much with Drew Khoury's answer, with one change. To download compose.phar, you can use the [remote_file resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_remote_file.html) instead of doing a wget in a bash script.

Comment: Added a comment to Drews answer saying why I now longer download composer.phar at all.

Answer (score 2):

As `composer.phar` is already an executable, you could simply put it to a dir in your `$PATH`:

```
remote_file '/usr/bin/composer' do
    source 'http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar'
    mode '0755'
    action :create_if_missing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your git hook post-receive to something like that:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/your/site
cd /path/to/your/site
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
# do your stuff here
```

And make sure to give executable permissions to the post-receive file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just commit your vendor directory. We have a couple projects running on Laravel 4 and OpsWorks.

Comment: @duellsy What are the downsides except increasing your repository size? If you have a paying client that expects his solution to last i don't want to put it in the hands of some random strangers to keep their repositories online. Don't get me wrong, I'm grateful for the work people put into Composer and their libraries but people loose interest, get sick etc.

Comment: increasing repo size is one concern, but then there's also the issue of a hugely bloated commit history flooded with other peoples updates that are completely unrelated to my project

Comment: @duellsy True, that has to be considered, but there are no technical implications, right?

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same position with Laravel and OpsWorks. I was looking for a solution but then...

What happens if someone injects a security flaw into one of the sub modules? Does that mean we trust X number of external code-bases to be 100% secure all the time?

Either there is some fundamental flaw in my understanding or running composer at all on a production server is about the most serious WTF there is.

I've now made sure that the code in my project repo will be deployed 100% as is. No downloading external modules on the production server ever.

Comment: That's exactly what the composer.lock file is for, it makes sure that you are downloading an exact version of the package that you were working locally with. See http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file

Comment: Exact version or exact code (verified by checksum for example)? How do we know that the code is identical to what is in the dev environment?

Comment: Exact version, which really, is exact code. When you do a `composer update` it updates the composer.lock file with the versions of each package. If you then run `composer install` on another machine, it downloads packages based on the version numbers in the composer.lock file NOT just blindly downloads latest versions of packages.