# How should git submodules be set up for laravel 4 composer packages?

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, git-submodules

I'm building an app with laravel 4, and am looking to deploy to a cloud server for further testing. The general process I usually do is local > push to github > clone to server.

The problem with this is that pretty much all of the laravel/composer packages I've added are ignored because they have their own git repos – I didn't really think about this beforehand.

I understand the concept of submodules, but I'm not quite understanding how to set them up. Do I have to add a submodule in the parent tree for every package I install to the app? Is there a more automated way of handling this?

Or am I completely off, and should these be updated on the server with composer?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer is composer:
http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md

add /vendor to the .gitignore file, and run composer install after the first clone.

Answer (score 1):

When using Composer you don't have to care about Git submodules at all.

On your local machine you just specify your dependencies in your `composer.json` and then run `composer install`. Now add your `composer.json` **and** `composer.lock` to your project repository, but exclude the `vendor` directory in your `.gitignore`.

Now to deploy your project, just clone or pull your project repository on your production server and then run `composer install` again to install all your project dependencies.

When you make changes to your dependencies you do the exact same process again, including `composer install` on your local and production machines.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a serious mistake to run composer on a production server. See [Getting started with chef, and running composer install on deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072524/getting-started-with-chef-and-running-composer-install-on-deploy/16506970#16506970)